# How do I make my discord bot leave Voice Chat with slash commands?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I've made my discord bot join VC with a Slash Command like so :

```
@Client.tree.command(name = "join", description="Join Vc")
async def join(interaction: discord.Interaction):
  channel = interaction.user.voice.channel
  await interaction.response.send_message("Joining...")
  await channel.connect()
```

but I'm not able to make it leave the VC, I thought it would be as easy as:

```
await channel.disconnect()
```

but apparently its not that easy it gives me this error:

```
AttributeError: 'VoiceChannel' object has no attribute 'disconnect'
```

I've tried a few other ways I found on here but non of them were either compatible with the current version or just gave me the same error, maybe I'm just overlooking something completely obvious.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try to disconnect from Voice Client instead Voice Channel:

```
async def leave(ctx):
   vc = discord.utils.get(self.bot.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
   await vc.disconnect()
```

As it is described [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/discordbots/comments/u86gi5/voicechannel_object_has_no_attribute_disconnect/).

Comment: I just tried this and it gives me a name error, "self is not defined"

Answer (score 1):

Ok I solved it on my own!

```
await interaction.guild.voice_client.disconnect()
```